# ios my object isn't being released

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

```
- (void)fadeOutSplash {
    UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape~ipad.png"]];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:splash]; // <-- OBJECT IS BEING RETAINED HERE

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{
                         splash.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [splash removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

I think ARC is retaining my "splash" when I add it to the subview of the `rootViewController`. ARC should release "splash" when I run my animation completion because it removes my "splash" from it's own super view. However, I can see in the allocation instruments that this parent view controller is staying allocated and it shows the problem line being where splash is added to the `rootViewController`. What can I do to make sure "splash" is released?

Comment: You're saying the parentViewController is staying allocated. If I don't misunderstand you, that's as it should be. Of course the Window's rootViewController (I guess that's the one you mean) is staying allocated - viewControllers and views are two different hierarchies. Now, are you sure the UIView "splash" is staying in memory? I get the feeling there's either a big misunderstanding, or you're not showing crucial parts of the code.

Comment: Jackson, You say: "I think ARC is retaining my "splash"  ...". Do you know for sure that this is the case? (ARC is very smart about such things. You are making an unlikely diagnosis.) Does Instruments tell you that you are leaking? Instruments can tell you where you are bing allocated and where the retain count is being modified. Does it identify this particular block as the culprit? Andrew

Comment: I don't know that for sure. It's the line that my allocations instrument highlighted in red with a 99.9% next to it. Seeing those two things, I made an assumption from there. What should I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem, but I'm not exactly sure how.. Here's the likely solution:

```
- (void)removeFromSuperView
{
    // Use this space to manually release any non IB pointers / variables as needed
    self.someDictionaryIMadeInInit = nil;

    while(self.subviews.count > 0) [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView];
    [super removeFromSuperView];
}
```

This a little trick I came up with for ARC related views. I recommend it more as a last resort because truly this should be solved the appropriate way, but it's worth a try to save you from tearing out your hair!